# Paas value from colorbox popup to parent window

Tags: javascript, jquery

this  following code is not working

//method 1 not working

```
    function show_val()
    {
        var payment_desc = $('#payment_desc').val();
        var pay_type_radio = $('input:radio[name=pay_type]:checked').val();

        window.parent.open("list_customer.php?task=paid&id="+id+"&pay_type="+pay_type_radio+"&payment_desc="+payment_desc+"","_self");
        window.parent.jQuery.colorbox.close(); 
    }
```

//method 2 not working

```
    function show_val()
    {
        var payment_desc = $('#payment_desc').val();
        var pay_type_radio = $('input:radio[name=pay_type]:checked').val();

        window.parent.location='list_customer.php?task=paid&id='+id+'&pay_type='+pay_type_radio+'&payment_desc='+payment_desc;
        window.parent.jQuery.colorbox.close(); 
    }
```

i want to pass values as GET/POST to parent window. above code is in colorbox popup. below is code in parent window (PHP)

```
    if(isset($_GET['id']) && $_GET['task']=='paid')
    {

    }
```

Comment: What you want ? What you get? Raise your problem clearly..

Comment: Showing any error in console?

Comment: i think your problem is that. your js variable `id` is not defined.

Comment: No my variable is defined problem is  that when i execute code without any parameter window.parent.location='list_customer.php' its works but when i execute code with parameter window.parent.location='list_customer.php?task=paid&id='+id it's not working.

Comment: check what you are getting in your php using `print_r($_GET);`

Comment: Thanks  CJ Ramki  there is conflict error in console. its working now.